# Is it possible to make the subscriber wait 3 seconds before retrieving the last message from the topic?

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am implementing a simple MQTT subscriber using PAHO, and it is working fine.
But I was told that the subscriber should not receive all messages sent to the topic, but instead it should get one message every 3 seconds (the last that was sent).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, messages are delivered to the subscriber by the broker as they arrive, they are not pulled/collected.

There is nothing to stop you adding incoming messages to a queue in the client an processing them at what ever rate you want, but this has nothing to do with MQTT or the Paho client.